# Why does preProcess ignore some columns when scaling all columns?

Tags: r, r-caret, preprocessor, r-haven

I have a data set - no missing values anywhere. I read it into R using package 'haven' - the file itself was an SPSS file ".sav" - so I used "read_sav".

I want to standardize all numeric columns using caret's pre-process.
Important: here is the structure of some of my columns:

```
> str(md$perc_51)
Class 'labelled'  atomic [1:2259] 4 3 5 5 5 3 5 5 4 4 ...
  ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Strongly Disagree" "Disagree" "Neither agree nor disagree" "Agree" ...
```

Some other columns have structure like this:

```
> str(md$Purchase12mTab)
 num [1:2259] 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 ...
```

Now, I try to scale all variables in my data set:

```
transfParams <- preProcess(md[-1:-2], method = c("center", "scale"))
transformed <- predict(transfParams, md[-1:-2])
```

When I check the results, I find that only columns whose structure was simply 'num' got scaled. All labeled columns remained untouched.

I am surprised - is there some kind of an unwritten rule that only non-labeled columns get processed? Or is there a conflict between caret and haven?

Comment: Providing a reproducible example and the results of `sessionInfo` will help get your question answered.